# SwiftMailer error log show nothing

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

SwiftMailer on Symfony2.

I try to send email by SqiftMailer, this code returns `[SWIFTMAILER] Success!!` though,
no log appears and no email sent.

I put the logger plugin though,
`$mailLogger->dump()` shows no log.

```
        $mailLogger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($mailLogger));


        $bodyText = $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render('AcmeTopBundle:Default:dailyAlert.txt.twig',array('data' => $this->data));
        $messaggio = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject("My Title")
            ->setContentType("text/html")
            ->setFrom($this->getContainer()->getParameter('receive_system_mail'))
            ->setTo($m->getUser()->getEmail())

            ->setBody(nl2br($bodyText));

        if ($this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($messaggio)){
            echo '[SWIFTMAILER] Success!! ' .   $mailLogger->dump() . "\n";
        }else {
            echo '[SWIFTMAILER] Fail ' . $mailLogger->dump() . "\n";
        }
```

In my config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    host: smtp.zoho.com
    username:  taro
    password:  ********
    port:      465
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode: plain

    spool:
     type: file
     path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool"
#    spool: {type: memory}
```

Comment: Can you print the configuration file?

Comment: @Delparo I added the config.yml

Comment: Your auth_mode configuration line may be incorrect? Did you try to play with the configurations ? Like trying with TLS mode instead of SSL mode?

Comment: I am not sure yet this configuration is completely OK though, For now I wonder why the error message appeares? or Why $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($messaggio) returns true??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use spool for mailing, mails firstly store in folder.
You should run bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send command to send them.
When you call send() function it just return count of mails.